# NotFound at field "card_nonce" error

Tags: square-connect

I get this error on test/**sandbox** but **not** in production.

InvalidRequestError - NotFound at field "card_nonce" : Resource not found.

I am passing it, see:

[image]

Please let me know what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when testing Square

- use the sandbox/test application id
- you cannot use production access keys - and you cannot generate access keys (for test)
- you must hard code in the sandbox access key - so all your test sites use that same key

That will fix this above mentioned issue.

Comment: I am getting error.

`CreateCustomerCardRequest createCustomerCardRequest = new CreateCustomerCardRequest("sq0idp-HHRL8jUWmdUV7OsUhczXEw", billingAddress, "Demo Visa")`;

Comment: Error is `{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"NOT_FOUND","detail":"Resource not found.","field":"card_nonce"}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the **App ID** used for the sandbox card nonce creation matches the one you are using for the sandbox Charge request? The sandbox App ID should have the *sandbox-* prefix.

Comment: I have added my Sandbox App ID but still the problem remain as same `Resource not found`
`public 'category' => string 'INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR' (length=21) public 'code' => string 'NOT_FOUND' (length=9) public 'detail' => string 'Resource not found.' (length=19)public 'field' => string 'card_nonce' (length=10)`

Comment: I am testing it in Local should I need to move it on server for testing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the `card_nonce` attribute. This attribute must be generated from `SqPaymentForm`as the [documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge) indicates:

> A nonce generated from the SqPaymentForm that represents the card to
>   charge. The application that provides a nonce to this endpoint must be
>   the same application that generated the nonce with the SqPaymentForm.
>   Otherwise, the nonce is invalid.

So I recommend to use the [test cases](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2) that Square proposes and then add to your platform.